# Como injetar o HttpContext em uma classe usando Injeção de dependência

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, injeção-de-dependência, simple-injector

Tenho seguinte cenário, tenho uma classe que realiza acesso ao banco de dados através do nome do usuário autenticado na máquina, para fazer essa conexão preciso desse nome para realizar um `replace` do `User Id` da string de conexão para ter acesso ao banco.

Consigo pegar esse **nome de usuário** usando o `HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`.
Estou tentando injetar o `HttpContext` na minha classe de conexão através da biblioteca do `SimpleInjector`, porém não estou conseguindo, quando tento dar o `bind` para tentar resolver a dependência ele emite esse erro:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'For the container to be able to create HttpContext it should have only one public constructor: it has 2. See https://simpleinjector.org/one-constructor for more information.
Arg_ParamName_Name
```

Entendo que o erro é porque o HttpContext não possui um construtor válido para resolver as dependências. Então como injetar essa classe na minha classe de conexão? Ou como pegar esse nome do usuário `logado` na máquina e injetar na minha classe de conexão?

***Exemplo da classe de conexão:***

```
public class DbSession 
{

    private HttpContext _context;

    private OracleConnection _Connection;

    private string ConnectionStrings = "Data Source=SERVIDOR; pooling=false; User id={#USUARIO}; Password=SENHA";

    public DbSession(HttpContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        OpenConnection();
    }
    
    private void OpenConnection()
    {
        var nome = _context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
        ConnectionStrings = ConnectionStrings.Replace("{#USUARIO}", nome);
        _Connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionStrings);
    }   

}
```

***Exemplo dos meus registros dentro do Global.asax***

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

// registro dos tipos das minhas instâncias
container.Register<HttpContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<DbSession>(Lifestyle.Scoped);


container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
container.Verify();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

Senão for possível com o `SimpleInjector`, gostaria de saber se existe outra biblioteca de injeção de dependência que resolva isso.

Estou usando os ASPNET MVC5 rodando o NETFramework 4.6.1 ( é um projeto legado )

Answer (score 0):

Eu diria que você não deveria passar o HttpContext para a sua classe DbSession.

Qual o motivo? Responsabilidades de cada classe. Pelo nome DbSession, consigo entender que essa classe vai ser um tipo de "Manager" de acesso a base de dados. HttpContext é contexto HTTP, portanto não faz sentido receber o contexto HTTP (Web) em algo de context de base de dados. Faz sentido?!

Dito isso, precisamos do nome do usuário nessa sua classe DbSession, minha recomendação seria criar uma outra classe onde seriam suas dependências, algo do tipo DbConnectionInput, DbConnectionParams. Você iria construir essa sua classe no momento que precisasse dela, iria registrar via Dependency Injection e depois receber na sua DbSession.

Dessa forma você iria resolver 2 problemas de uma só vez. Código mais organizado e vai resolver seu problema atual.

Keep coding!

Comment: o motivo de eu querer passar o `HttpContext` é porque o acesso o banco é através do usuários e senha da rede, então ele tem que ser feito no momento da entrada do usuário na aplicação.

Comment: Mas realmente eu estou viajando, é só eu criar uma interface para retorna essa informação, injetando ele na classe `DbSession` e implementar na minha aplicação MVC, aí consigo resolver via injeção de dependência sem infringir nenhuma reponsabilidade.